# Creating an ASP.NET diagnostics page to be pinged by Load Balancer

Tags: asp.net, load-balancing, health-monitoring, diagnostics

Our server operations team has asked the web development team (ASP.NET) to provide a URL in our application, which the load balancer can ping to perform health checks.

What should be executed on this page? I think we should attempt a database connection to ensure connectivity between the web and database. Anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really you want to check the database configuration, asp.net configuration, web.config and any other web services or dependencies.

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/selfdiagnostics.aspx) is a really great codeproject that will get you started with minimal coding.

Answer (score 1):

Your health-check page should ping any external dependencies in your application and make sure everything is responding properly. That includes:

- Databases
- Web Services
- Dynamically Loaded DLLs
- COM+ Components

If all the tests pass, then the health-check page should respond properly so the load balancer can use that server.

Comment: This could be an expensive call, especially for a complex application with lots of dependencies... I could understand using this for a monitoring server that is called every minute or so, but the Load Balancer is checking every couple seconds. Also, suppose 1 out of 10 dependent web services is down for 2 minutes. This means that ALL nodes in the web farm would quickly be taken out of rotation. So a partial failure means everything goes down.

Comment: It could also be expensive for a web server that runs many apps simultaneously.